# Where can I find a bug collection to import into FindBugs?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, findbugs

I'm using the FindBugs-IDEA plugin for IntelliJ.
It finds much less bugs than our SonarQube (SonarQube uses FindBugs under the hood).
The plugin says I can Import/Export a bug collection from xml or html. Where can I find these collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to import the same list of rules than what is configured in your SonarQube instance, you can go to "Quality Profiles > Your_Quality_Profile > Permalinks": you will find a link that you can use to download the list of Findbugs rules configured in your quality profile.

For instance, take a look at this page on Nemo: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/profiles/permalinks/169

Then, you just need to import this downloaded file in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of all the things you can check for: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html

You can find more info on how to use this info here: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html